# Memory Leak with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android

I've encountered a memory leak with SwipeRefreshLayout and wondering if there's any way to maybe solve this with a workaround?

In a empty project, with a swipe layout as the root of the main activity, if you swipe down, and minimize the app while it's refreshing, even if you put a stop in onStop or onPause, it will continue to eat CPU/Battery as long as the app is open in the background.

The cpu profiler I attached will just repeatedly do what's in that image forever, and the energy profiler shows an always or almost always constant usage while backgrounded.

Any ideas on what I can do to stop this?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onStop() { //tried in onPause as well
        swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        swipeRefresh.clearAnimation() //I tried with/without this
        super.onStop()
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: During onStop, try to invoke swipeRefresh.destroyDrawingCache(). It is deprecated but I think it may help

Comment: @W0rmH0le no, still happens =(

Comment: I'm not sure how kotlin works, but I guess swipeRefresh.isRefreshing = false seems wrong to me... You can try invoking: swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false); or swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false, false); during onStop.

Comment: That's just a Kotlin thing.  I encountered the bug in Java and use setRefreshing(false)

Comment: Also the setRefreshing(false,false) is private =(

Comment: @Ben987654 .. I checked the android source code ,it seems setrefreshing() just cancel any visual indication of a refresh . 

try : 
swipeRefresh.isEnabled = false

Comment: I got it. But with setRefreshing(false) the bug still happens?

Comment: @Ashishsingh Looks like disabling the view works.  You the need to re-enable it onStart/onResume though, but that works until Google addresses it.  If you add that as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In onPause

```
swipeRefresh.isEnabled = false
```

OnResume

```
swipeRefresh.isEnabled = true
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.  I've logged the issue with google so they can properly address it as well - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136153683